# C# Infer Nullability of Member Assigned Through Ref Parameter During Construction

Tags: c#, ref, nullable-reference-types

I have some shorthand for setting property values in a Xamarin app:

```cs
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
        return false;
    storage = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    return true;
}
```

This is used in my ViewModels, for example:

```cs
class PersonViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => SetProperty(ref name, value);
    }
    public PersonViewModel(string theName) {
        Name = theName;
    }
}
```

When I have `#nullable enable`, how can I (in the general case, whenever `SetProperty` is used) help the compiler infer that the `name` member is not null after construction?

Currently, I get a warning on the constructor which says:
"CS8618: Non-nullable property 'Name' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.".

I'm using `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` in my `.csproj`.

Comment: Where do you get a warning exactly ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use [`NotNullIfNotNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullifnotnullattribute?view=net-5.0) to say that "`storage` is not null if `value` is not null".

See [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(
    [NotNullIfNotNull("value")] ref T storage,
    T value,
    [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
{
    if (object.Equals(storage, value))
        return false;
    storage = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    return true;
}
```

In the constructor, you need to do:

```
SetProperty(ref name, theName);
```

rather than setting the property normally, because the compiler doesn't know that these two are the same thing.

Edit: I just noticed that in .NET 5.0, they added [`MemberNotNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.membernotnullattribute?view=net-5.0), so your constructor can stay like this:

```
public PersonViewModel(string theName)
{
    Name = theName;
}
```

You just have to mark the setter with the attribute:

```
public string Name
{
    get => name;
    [MemberNotNull(nameof(name))]
    set => SetProperty(ref name, value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as already said, the compiler does not know how `Name` and `name` are connected, so you should set the `name` property exactly how you would in `Name` setter. But this won't get rid out of warning, but you can use null-forgiving operator `!`, see samlpe code:

```
public class Cls
{
    public Cls(string n)
    {
        SetValue(ref name!, n);
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => SetValue(ref name, value);
    }
    private void SetValue<T>(ref T store, T value) => store = value;
}
```